# How do I convert a JSON message from RabbitMQ to a Java object?

Tags: java, json, spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have two separate Java apps which I need to send messages between via RabbitMQ using spring-rabbit. In the app which is the producer I am using `JsonMessageConverter` as the message converter for my `RabbitTemplate` to convert my Java objects to JSON messages before they get sent to the queue.

In the other app which is the consumer I want to convert the JSON messages back to Java objects. I have tried using `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` with a custom `MessageListener` and I can get the `Message`s from the queue, but I don't know to convert them from JSON back to Java objects.

How do I use `JsonMessageConverter` when consuming messages asynchronously from RabbitMQ?

Comment: Can you show how do you use `JsonMessageConverter` in producer and how you get messages in consumer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up using a `MessageListenerAdapter` with a custom delegate object and `JsonMessageConverter` as the `MessageConverter`. Like so:

```
SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
listenerContainer.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(new EventHandler(), new JsonMessageConverter()));
```

My `EventHandler` class has a single method called handleMessage which gets the deserialized JSON object passed to it.